# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position but there is a row

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have 3 rows in Grid.Datatable but when execute this code:

```
grid.SetValue(2,"ColumnName",1) --index,columnName,value--
```

throw exeption:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 2.
> at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
> at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at BLUEOCEAN.WINUI.ACTX20100000.GetDataOriginTab6(Int32 index, String col)

anyone know why?

Comment: Rows are numbered from 0, not from 1. Did you account for that?

Comment: Drat, I lost my magic ball, which allows me to look on other people's computer. Sorry, without that, and with you giving no [mcve], I cannot help